# How to correctly pass sockets to a function's parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, law-of-demeter

If I create a global socket object like so..

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

and define a function like so..

```
def function():
    <do something with the socket object>
```

Would it be considered non-dry programming if I passed the socket object as a function parameter for readability, is this the approach I should take when using sockets inside functions that are declared globally or within a while loop?

Example:

```
def function(passed_sock):
    <do something with the socket object>
```

Comment: Its better not to have global variables in the first place, but even if you do, its better for functions to take parameters for all the objects they need. (btw nothing to do with DRY).

Comment: This is a matter of readability? just making sure I understand correctly.

Comment: Ideally, functions should accept as parameters all the data they need, and explicitly return all the data that they produce. That isn't always feasible in every case, but it's a good guideline to follow when in doubt.

Comment: Related to Law of Demeter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter